# Question about derivative and limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

$f(x): [0,1]\to[0,1]$ - continuous function.

Let $f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x_0) - f(x)}{ x_0 - x }$
exists.

Consider the sequence of intervals $G_n = [ a(n), b(n) ]$,
where $ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have  $a(n)<b(n)<x_0$
and
$a(n) \to x_0$, $b(n) \to x_0$ at $n\to\infty$.

Is it true that
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{ b - a } = f'(x_0)$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the answer is no. Define
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2\sin(\frac1x), &\text{if } x\ne0, \\
0, & \text{if } x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
It can be shown that
$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases}
2x\sin(\frac1x)-\cos(\tfrac1x), &\text{if } x\ne0, \\
0, & \text{if } x=0
\end{cases}
$$
($x=0$ being the only nontrivial point). In particular, at every point of the form $x(n)=-\frac{1}{2n\pi}$ we have $f'(x(n)) = -1$. We then obtain a counterexample (with $x_0=0$) by choosing $a(n)=x(n)$ and $b(n)$ so close to $x(n)$ that $\frac{f(b(n))-f(x(n))}{b(n)-x(n)}$ is very close to $-1$, which is possible since $\lim_{b(n)\to x(n)} \frac{f(b(n))-f(x(n))}{b(n)-x(n)} = f'(x(n))$.

This counterexample essentially comes from the fact that $f'(x)$ exists at all points but is not continuous. It's less clear whether the OP's question can be answered in the affirmative if one assumes that $f'(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Interesting! Though, I believe, if I consider $a(n)<x_0<b(n)$, then the statement would be true? ( In this case $x_0$ would be the (only) intersection point of all $G_n$'s. )
If so, there's rhetorical question on why is that, since the existence of the limit allows us to converge from any side we want. And intuitively there should be no difference between converging from both sides and converging "twice" from one side.